# SQL Server BETWEEN not as efficient

Tags: sql-server

I recall hearing or reading somewhere that

```
SELECT * from TABLE where date >= '2009-01-01' AND date <= '2009-12-31'
```

is more efficient than

```
SELECT * from TABLE where date BETWEEN '2009-01-01' AND '2009-12-31'
```

Where date column is a DATETIME type and has the same index.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not, it's not correct.

Both syntaxes are absolutely same.

`BETWEEN` is just a syntax sugar, a shorthand for `>= … AND <= …`

Same is true for all major systems (`Oracle`, `MySQL`, `PostgreSQL`), not only for `SQL Server`.

However, if you want to check for the date to be in the current year, you should use this syntax:

```
date >= '2009-01-01' AND date < '2010-01-01'
```

Note that the last condition is strict.

This is *semantically* different from `BETWEEN` and it is a preferred way to query for the current year (rather than `YEAR(date) = 2009` which is not sargable).

You cannot rewrite this condition as a `BETWEEN` since the last inequality is strict and `BETWEEN` condition includes the range boundaries.

You need the strict condition since `DATETIME`'s, unlike integers,  are not [well-ordered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order), that is you cannot tell the "last possible datetime value in `2009`" (which is not implementation-specific, of course).

Comment: Easiest way to answer these questions is look at the execution plan for both statements.  You'll probably find the plans are identical with identical costs.

Comment: One SQL Server 2012, `DATE_TIME between '01/01/2013' and '01/01/14'` is the syntactical equivalent of `DATE_TIME >= '01/01/2013' and DATE_TIME < '01/01/14'`.  Both are sargable.

Comment: @craig: did you mean `CAST(DATE_TIME AS DATE) BETWEEN '01/01/2013' and '01/01/14'` in the first expression?

Comment: @Quassnoi: No, I wanted to document the behavior with a date/time value.  However, `CAST(DATE_TIME AS DATE) BETWEEN '01/01/2013' AND '12/31/2013'` is functionally equivalent (same results) to `DATE_TIME between '01/01/2013' and '01/01/14'`--both have the same cost.  That said, the `CAST()` operation has quite a few more operations (e.g. `Compute Scalar`, `Merge Interval`), than the non-cast syntax.

Comment: @craig: if we talk `datetime` the type, then `between '01/01/2013' and '01/01/14'` and `DATE_TIME >= '01/01/2013' and DATE_TIME < '01/01/14'` are not syntactically equivalent: the first one matches `2014-01-01 00:00:00.000`, the second one doesn't. And the `CAST` operation does not have any extra operations: it's just rewritten by the optimizer to your second expression.

Comment: @Quassnoi: you are right--my data didn't contain a `01/01/14 00:00:00.000` value.  The [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/01a53/3) for verification.